# How to validate inactive tabs bootstrapvalidator

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that submit doesn't validate other tabs. If I remove hidden from excluded list it validates but the problem it also then validates hidden input boxes.
How can i get it to validate all tabs but not validate hidden fields inside the tabs? How to fix this?

Here is some of the code from the validation section-.

```
jQuery('#form').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#messages',
        excluded: [':disabled'],
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: { 
                Name: {
                    validators: {                       
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Name is required.'
                                  }
                       }
                  },
             EmployerName: {
                 validators: {

                     notEmpty: {
                         message: 'Employer Name required.'
                     }
                  },
             JobTitle: {
                 validators: {

                     notEmpty: {
                         message: 'JobTitle required.'
                     }
                  }...
```

Name field is on the active tab
EmployerName & Job Title are in seperate tab to Name. 
Job Title is in a Div that is hidden.

When code runs Job Title is validated as well as Employer Name. Job Title shouldnt be as its hidden. If i include hidden in the excluded list, EmployerName doesnt validate anymore. I hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: Please post any code related to the question you are asking, in order to better get assistance on your question

Comment: updated description above.